# sum case issue , no column for groupby clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query:

```
SELECT leads,
       touched,
       invalid,
       TQL,
       SQOs,
       Wins,
       (touched / (CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), leads)) * 100) AS [touch%],
       (t.invalid / touched) AS [Invalid Leads%],
       (TQL / (CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), touched)) * 100) AS [TQL %],
       (SQOs / (CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), TQL)) * 100) AS [SQO%],
       (Wins / (CONVERT(decimal(7, 2), TQL)) * 100) AS [Wins%]
FROM (SELECT COUNT([lead id]) AS leads,
             SUM(CASE
                      WHEN a.status = 'Disqualified'
                        OR a.status = 'Qualified'
                       AND a.[Status Reason] <> 'Expired' THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                 END) AS touched,
             SUM(CASE
                      WHEN a.status = 'Disqualififed'
                       AND a.[Status Reason] IN ('Already Engaged', 'Already purchased', 'Invalid Contact Info', 'Misrouted Lead', 'Non-Supported Market', 'Partner') THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                 END) AS invalid,
             SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Qualified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TQL,
             SUM(CASE WHEN b.status = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SQOs,
             SUM(CASE WHEN b.status = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins,
             CASE WHEN b.status = 'Won' THEN SUM([End Cust Purchase Amount Const $])END AS tqlrevenue
      FROM lead a
           LEFT JOIN opportunity b ON a.[Opportunity Id (Qualifying Opportunity) (Opportunity)] = b.[Opportunity Id]
           LEFT JOIN MSSalesMalaysia_Updated c ON b.[Opportunity Id] = c.[opp id]
      WHERE a.[Lead Source] = 'Marketing') t;
```

When I add the expression `case when B.status ='Won' then sum([End Cust Purchase Amount Const $]) end as tqlrevenue` I get the following error:

> Column 'opportunity.Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Now all columns in subquery are case conditions, which column to include?

Comment: Should the `CASE` not be inside the `SUM`, not outside of it, like all the other expressions you have? I.e. `SUM(CASE WHEN a.status = 'Qualified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TQL`. This seems like a typographical error.

Comment: `CASE WHEN b.status = 'Won' THEN SUM([End Cust Purchase Amount Const $])END AS tqlrevenue` should be in group by

Comment: On a different note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @DigvijayS aggregate functions cannot appear inside the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want conditional aggregation:

```
sum(case when B.status ='Won' then [End Cust Purchase Amount Const $]) end) as tqlrevenue
```

That is, the `case` expression is the argument to `sum()`.